# Why backdrop filter in Firefox don't work?

Tags: css, firefox, blur

I use backdrop-filter: blur(30px); but firefox unsupported this property;
-moz-backdrop-filter: blur(60px); also doesn't work

Comment: It now works in the latest version of firefox as of right now (103). You can now use blur!

Comment: I'll go celebrate it!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Its not supported by default https://caniuse.com/css-backdrop-filter

However you can activate it manually.

Navigate to `about:config` and set it to `true`
[image]

Comment: can I use other property without backdrop-filter to set the blur?

Comment: @АндрійКотюга well i dont know

Comment: interestingly Mozilla site describes it very well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter  . but the demo part itself only works in chrome or safari. I'm not sure why FF doesn't support it by default!

Comment: The reason why it's not yet available by default is that there are still issues with the feature. It's tracked as a bug here: [Enable the CSS backdrop-filter property by default (letting it ride the trains to release)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1578503)

Comment: Looks like as of Firefox 96 this feature was disabled or requires extra steps to enable that I'm not aware of. It stopped working for me after upgrading.

Answer (score 7):

As described on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter, both `layout.css.backdrop-filter.enabled` and `gfx.webrender.all` have to be set to true.

**Important: the browser must be restarted for it to work**

Comment: This is experimental feature for a reason, still. I've tried it on some websites I've built, and while they work perfectly in Chrome and Safari, they look terrible in Firefox. Styles aren't calculated correctly and it may happen that the entire screen becomes blurred.

Answer (score 6):

I just wanted to point out that, as of yesterday, the newest Firefox Nightly Release does support backdrop-filter after enabling `gfx.webrender.all` and `layout.css.backdrop-filter.enabled` in `about:config`.

It will also be officially implemented in Version 102 (which will be released on 28.06.2022) as far as I could grasp that.

Comment: Update: The feature got postponed to 103, which, however, already released, so the feature is now officially live!

Comment: It doesn't work on 105 for me. Feels like I'm taking crazy pills

Answer (score 1):

Firefox officially support it since version `103`. In my case I was using Firefox-esr and at the moment I write this latest ESR version is `102.7.0esr`. I had to switch to non-esr version (`109.0` right now) to make it work.