# Why does the CSS backdrop-filter property not work in Firefox on some of my devices?

Tags: css, firefox

The CSS property backdrop-filter does not work in Firefox on some of my devices, whereas on others it does work. I use version 86.0 now, but it hasn’t worked before either.

As mentioned in an answer to a similar question ([Why backdrop filter in Firefox don't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63789769/why-backdrop-filter-in-firefox-dont-work)) an on MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter) I turned on `layout.css.backdrop-filter.enabled` and `gfx.webrender.all`, but it hasn’t changed anything, it still doesn’t work.

My device is quite old, it is a Lenovo T61 notebook. Is it possible that the hardware is unable to do that?

In Chromium, it works, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this link. Not supported in Firefox
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter

Comment: Yes, I have read that. But as mentioned on this page, I have turned on both properties in `about:config`, but that doesn’t work as described on some of my devices.
But on all devices I use the same Firefox version, and on some devices it works and on some it doesn’t.